# Openvpn w/ Network manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

This may be a shot in the dark. I'm setting up a Ubuntu 12.04 computer in an open area in which each user need their own username and password to access the network via VPN. This must be a very simple task. Which is why I choose network manager. But Network manager requires a username to be place in a text box and saved in editing VPN connection. Is their a way to make it ask with saving the config for a username and password?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it. You wish to NM always ask for u/p combination.

1. start NM
2. select vpn connection
3. go to configuration
4. on tab VPN section Optional right from pass you have list box and can pick option "Always Ask"